# What is the xpath proper syntax for and contains text()?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have the following xpath:

```
By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'foo123') and contains(text(), 'foo bar')]")
```

I am trying to find the following html:

```
<div class="foo123">foo bar</div>
```

Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the syntax is correct. If you're not getting the result you expected, please tell what result you're getting.

Comment: Did you mean to have the `.` at the start? That will scope the search to the current "parent", i.e rather than the whole document it will usually be the current element you've got.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to uniquely select an element. If I omit the contains text part and instead do something like this: driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'foo123')]").size() it will return <x> elements (in this case 1). When I write the same but use the and contains text() it will return 0.

Comment: yes the . was intended. I'm basically doing a parent.child.child

Comment: @Matt, `.//` is definitely not "basically doing a parent.child.child".   It is selecting the current context node (`.`) itself and descendents thereof.

Comment: What I meant is that the way my elements are structured is I store each element in a separate class file. element 1 will be driver.findelement(by.className("container1")). element 2 will be element1.findElement(By.xpath(".// xcode expression")) and so on for related elements. Are you saying this is a bad way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I was confused because webdriver .getText() and xpath's text() do not do the same things. In this example the div I was actually looking for was like the following:

```
<div class="divSelected">
    <div class="div1" />
    <div class="divwithtext"> text </div>
    <div class="div3"/>
</div>
```

in webdriver if I do divSelected.getText() it will give me "text". The xpath text() will not.

Comment: So, for your future questions, make sure you give enough information (e.g. a `div` structure that represents your actual problem).